# transfering folder to a remote machine using paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to copy some folder to a remote machine both running on linux. Below is the code i used, i am not sure what need to be added for copy to happen

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('xxx.xxx.xx.xx', username='root', 
    password='xxxxxxx')
#scp -r /mnt/hgfs/windows-D-drive/Testing/ root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:/home # equivalent code here
```

Comment: basically i need to transfer directory -(with sub directories) form windows/linux machine to a remote machine running on linux through python

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way here is to zip the file and use the sftp.put to place the file on remote machine and extract it over remote machine:

```
tar = tarfile.open("Tests.tar.gz", "w:gz")
path_me = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
tar.add(path_me, arcname="Tests")
tar.close()

transport = paramiko.Transport((SERVER_IP, 22))
transport.connect(username = 'root', password = 'xxxxx')

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
remotepath='/home/Tests.tar.gz'
localpath=os.path.join(path_me+"/Tests.tar.gz")
#print(localpath)
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
transport.close()

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(SERVER_IP, username='root', password='philips')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("tar -C /home -xzf /home/Tests.tar.gz")
```

Answer (score 1):

## I did it by sending files one by one with same tree structure at destination.

```
import paramiko
import os

client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
with open ("/home/vikas/Desktop/password.txt" ) as a:
    ip,username,password=a.readline().split(" ")
client.connect(hostname=ip,username=username ,password=password)
sftp_client=client.open_sftp()

#client.exec_command("cd") 
# LETS make 'aaaa' folder sync with server 
#/root/ is home for remote server 

localfolder="/home/vikas/Desktop/aaaa/"
basefolder="/".join(localfolder.split("/")[:-2])

for path,dirs,files in os.walk(localfolder):
    if path.lstrip(localfolder)!=None:       
        extrapath=path.split(basefolder)[-1]   
        command="mkdir /root/{}".format(extrapath)   
        client.exec_command(command)

    for file in files:  
        filepath=os.path.join(path,file)
        extrapath=path.split(basefolder)[-1]
        sftp_client.put(filepath,"/root/{}/{}".format(extrapath,file))
sftp_client.close()
client.close()
```